# Android TextView font changed between devices

Tags: android, textview

I have application that uses define no TypeFace in none of its TextView.

I've tested it in different devices, and when the device has a different font - it change the font of my application.

How can i set the default font of all TextView to the android default, and not the user defined one ?

Comment: It's normal that an app uses the system font. For older devices it was DROID. Nowadays it's ROBOTO. Plus, if the user changes the system font by any means, you app too will use it. Unless you don't set a specific TypeFace (and store your font into the assets folder)

Comment: can i use TypeFace of Droid ?

Comment: If you put it in your assets folder, yes. It's free to download.